# HTTP Request to external API blocked by CORS policy from every origin except localhost

Tags: javascript, api, http, cors, localhost

I'm creating an Angular application with which I want to use the DEGIRO public API. Something is going wrong with **cross-origin requests** between my application and the **external API**.

**When** I run the application on **localhost** with `ng serve` my preflight requests pass the access control check **perfectly**. However, I run into **problems** when I run the application with **any other origin** host like [any IPv4-address]:4200 with `ng serve --host [any IPv4-address]`. The same problem also occurs after deploying to for example Firebase.

To communicate with the API I use the HttpClientModule with Angular as shown in the image below.

[Angular HTTP POST API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut64W.jpg)

The problem I run into is described to me by the error message below.

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://trader.degiro.nl/login/secure/login' from origin
'http://192.168.178.120:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource."
```

The main reason this error confuses me is because it **doesn't happen from localhost**. In the two images below the differences between the preflight request headers(localhost:4200 & 192.168.178.52:4200) are shown. *Please note how the only differences are the origin and referer headers. The deployed application on Firebase is also similar like this.*

[Http request header (localhost)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H6H1.jpg)

[Http request header (IPv4-address)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M2sV.jpg)

I've tried skipping the preflight request by adding a `'content-type': 'text/plain'` header, but even the now simple request wouldn't be accepted by the CORS policy.

I have also read several somewhat similar issue's, but none of them matched my case perfectly and neither did their solutions. Next to these I have also read up a bit on CORS. I found this article very informative and helpful. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

I can't think of any more context. I hope this post is clear and you're able to help. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 0):

Did you request a session with VWD service?
As I can see first you need to make POST request to:

https://degiro.quotecast.vwdservices.com/CORS/request_session?version=1.0.20170315&userToken=YOUR_TOKEN

And provide header:`Origin: 'https://trader.degiro.nl'`
and provide body: `JSON.stringify({referrer: 'https://trader.degiro.nl'})`

After you get the session you use that to for example: get latest bid/ask prices for a VWD issue ID

Check [this package](https://github.com/pladaria/degiro) out, take look at how they managed to get it working.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hey ahmetovicajdin, thank you very much for replying so quickly. I won't be able to try this until tomorrow evening (GMT+1). As soon as I've had the time to try it, I'll update this post!

Comment: I've been trying this, but I keep getting a 401 response from https://degiro.quotecast.vwdservices.com/CORS/request_session?version=1.0.20170315&userToken=YOUR_TOKEN . Next to that I'm told I can't set the unsafe header of origin. Why do I need to use that link for the VWD service? Everything works on localhost. What do you think?